# Problem with configuration CTDB GlusterFS with Samba

Tags: centos7, samba, glusterfs

[image]I am trying to set up a HA GlusterFS (version 7.7) Replicated Distribution Storage Cluster on Centos 7. I read some docs and tutorials, but I am stuck at the moment with my CTDB setup. Is there someone whith experience with such configurations? I can use your help!

This error I get when starting smb service:

***ctdbd init connection: ctdbd_init_connection_internal failed (Input/output error) clustering=yes but ctdbd connect failed: Input/output error***